# Plotting polygon after scaling and rotation does not work

Tags: r, polygon, rgl

I have a polygon which I rotate and scale and subsequently want to display. When trying to plot it beforehands, everything works just fine:

```
library(rgl)

poly_nice <- data.frame(
  "x" = c(0, 0, 2, 2, 0.1,   3, 3, 5, 5, 3.1,   5, 6, 8, 10,  8,  6,    5,  3.1,  5,  5,  3,    3,  0.1,  2,  2,  0, 0),
  "y" = c(0, 2, 4, 2, 0.1, 0.1, 2, 4, 2, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1,  0, -1, -1, -0.1, -0.1, -2, -4, -2, -0.1, -0.1, -2, -4, -2, 0),
  "z" = c(0, 0, 0, 0,   0,   0, 0, 0, 0,   0,   0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,    0,    0,  0,  0,  0,    0,    0,  0,  0,  0, 0))

# plot 3d
open3d()
polygon3d(x = poly_nice$x, y = poly_nice$y, z = poly_nice$z)
```

[image: working 3d plot]

However, after scaling and rotating, it does not work anymore and I get the error `Error in processOutside(i) : Cannot triangulate polygon`.

```
poly_fail <- data.frame(
  x = c(0.757392934146312, 0.783538035845375, 0.771496532188989,
        0.745351430489926, 0.756790858963492, 0.701420281198091, 0.726258127812201, 
        0.714216624155816, 0.688071522456752, 0.699510950930319, 0.663233675842642, 
        0.655905668929496, 0.617719063574047, 0.566459907369066, 0.591573961874983, 
        0.629760567230433, 0.660619165672736, 0.696896440760412, 0.635781319058625, 
        0.609636217359562, 0.673967924414075, 0.698805771028185, 0.754176348793586, 
        0.693061227091799, 0.666916125392736, 0.731247832447248, 0.757392934146312),
  y = c(2.42738823177139, 2.48139224696605, 2.55388364086694, 
        2.49987962567227, 2.43101280146643, 2.45781950059045, 2.50912331502538, 
        2.58161470892627, 2.5276106937316, 2.45874386952576, 2.47630687929667, 
        2.50985237548738, 2.5283397541936, 2.51982512530248, 2.47433573899893, 
        2.45584836029271, 2.4709064777772, 2.45334346800629, 2.41960266334227, 
        2.3655986481476, 2.40111528463605, 2.45241909907098, 2.42561239994696, 
        2.39187159528294, 2.33786758008828, 2.37338421657672, 2.42738823177139),
  z = c(4.40259825958822, 4.40259825958822, 4.36017185271703, 
        4.36017185271703, 4.40047693924467, 4.33895864928144, 4.33895864928144, 
        4.29653224241024, 4.29653224241024, 4.33683732893788, 4.29653224241024, 
        4.27531903897465, 4.23289263210345, 4.19046622523226, 4.23289263210345, 
        4.27531903897465, 4.29653224241024, 4.33683732893788, 4.29653224241024, 
        4.29653224241024, 4.33895864928144, 4.33895864928144, 4.40047693924467, 
        4.36017185271703, 4.36017185271703, 4.40259825958822, 4.40259825958822))

# plot 3d
open3d()
polygon3d(x = poly_fail$x, y = poly_fail$y, z = poly_fail$z, coords = c(2,3))
# > Error in processOutside(i) : Cannot triangulate polygon
```

First, I thought I messed up the polygon, but when plotting it 2D, everything looks just fine:

```
# plot 2d
plot(poly_fail$x, poly_fail$y)
lines(poly_fail$x, poly_fail$y)
```

[image: working 2d plot]

What am I doing wrong? Is my polygon violating any rules I don't know of? It's not intersecting itself and it starts and ends with the same coordinates and the polygon is planar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think the issue is that the points 26, 27, 1, 2 form a perfectly straight line.  (Point 27 and point 1 are the same point, but that still leaves 3 sequential points in a straight line.)  If I fix this by these changes it works:

```
poly_fail[27,] <- poly_fail[2,]
poly_fail <- poly_fail[-1,]
polygon3d(poly_fail)
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed my "base" polygon to something which does not have a flat base and now it works for all of my rotations :) Although it's weird that it works when it's still flat and then later on it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: I'd guess it's a matter of rounding error:  some rotations end up just slightly off.

Comment: But shouldn't the "base" polygon have the highest risk of having points on a line, as up to this point the least rounding errors could have happened and I provided pretty round numbers?